# KeyboardAvoidingView using multiple inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling to understand and fix a problem I've been having when trying to use `KeyboardAvoidingView` to wrap some text inputs.

To aid my question, I've made an MVCE: https://snack.expo.io/@lee12f/brave-peanut

Please run this using the IOS simulator (or on IOS device) to reproduce the problem.

Clicking between the `TextInput` components (and around the screen) causes the `KeyboardAvoidingView` to toggle thus changing my `View` height. What am I doing wrong? How can I ensure the `KeyboardAvoidingView` remains enabled when clicking between the inputs?

As a bonus, it would be nice when clicking anywhere other than the inputs for the keyboard to close.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: If possible, without using 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

try using  `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` way easier to setup and it performs better in opinion

```
  import {KeyboardAwareScrollView}  from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
 
 <KeyboardAwareScrollView   contentContainerStyle={{ flex:1,display:'flex' }} >
    /... inputs here 
 </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: That library doesn't have the same functionality does it? In that It doesn't adjust a component height to avoid collision with the keyboard.

Comment: no in my case at least , it should wrap the whole component  try it it should easy to implement

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't seem to do what I want. I tried to wrap the two inputs inside a View (with quite a large height). Ideally, I'd want the view to move up entirely instead of just to the input.

Comment: I know what you mean just nest the input inside the KeyboardAwareScrollView  directly , so when you focus on input you can scroll up and down that's the behavior I have in my app

Comment: What happens If you have gestures? I have a swipe down to close model which seems to get a little muddy when using this new package..

Comment: Yes. I have a swipe down to go back to a previous view.

Comment: wait you said you had a modal, so is the modal the wrapper around your inputs please elaborate

Comment: Yes, inputs are inside a modal, which has a gesture handler attached which will close on swipe down.

Comment: what about the KeyboardAwareScrollView   is it scrolling fine ? also what did you mean by muddy ?  is it lagging

Comment: Yup scrolls fine. It just overrides my gestures, which isn't ideal. Can you think of a way of using the default KeyboardAvoidingView? Back to the original question.

Comment: I will try , meanwhile try this hack https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/420#issuecomment-600656985